# How clever java compiler is? Issues about enum method

Tags: java, enums, compiler-construction

Consider this situation:

Style1:

```
static enum Style1{
    FIRE_BALL {
        @Override
        public boolean isCold() {
            return false;
        }
    },ICE_BALL {
        @Override
        public boolean isCold() {
            return true;
        }
    },FIRE_ARROW {
        @Override
        public boolean isCold() {
            return false;
        }
    },ICE_ARROW {
        @Override
        public boolean isCold() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    public abstract boolean isCold();
}
```

Style2:

```
static enum Style2{
    FIRE_BALL,ICE_BALL,FIRE_ARROW,ICE_ARROW;
    public boolean isCold(){
        //return this.toString().contains("ICE")?true:false; //sorry
        return this.toString().contains("ICE");
    }
}
```

Now, I simply want to know whether it's cold. So I'm going to ask:

**Can compiler know the destined results and constant-fold Style2 ?**

If not, Style1 should be obviously faster, but more verbose. Assume this were more complicated situation and there were many more combinations, such as BIG_FIRE_SLOW_BALL with isFast(), isBig(), Style1 will end up with chunks of codes.

---

So I did some tests with jmh and jUnit:

1.with jmh:

```
@Benchmark
public boolean testStyle1() {
    return Style1.values()[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4)].isCold();
}

@Benchmark
public boolean testStyle2() {
    return Style2.values()[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4)].isCold();
}
```

when setting:

```
            .warmupIterations(10)
            .measurementIterations(10)
            .threads(8)

Benchmark             Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
EnumTest1.testStyle1  avgt   10  34.057 ± 0.101  ns/op
EnumTest1.testStyle2  avgt   10  36.196 ± 0.453  ns/op
```

well, set thread number to 1

```
            .threads(1)
Benchmark             Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
EnumTest1.testStyle1  avgt   10  34.306 ± 11.692  ns/op
EnumTest1.testStyle2  avgt   10  44.279 ± 11.103  ns/op
```

So, it seems like **Style2 can't be optimized by compiler.**

2,with jUnit:

```
private static final int LOOP_TIMES = 100000000;
private static final Random random1=new Random(47);
private static final Random random2=new Random(47);

@Test
public void testStyle1() {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_TIMES; i++) {
        if(Style1.values()[random1.nextInt(4)].isCold()){
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);
}

@Test
public void testStyle2() {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_TIMES; i++) {
        if(Style2.values()[random2.nextInt(4)].isCold()){
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);
}
```

results:

```
Time:      1       2       3    inverse order   4      5       6
Style1: 3.631s  4.578s  3.754s    Style2     4.131s  5.487s  4.261s  
Style2: 2.559s  4.216s  3.155s    Style1     2.316s  3.977s  4.152s
```

So, **Style1 is likely to be faster**.

---

**But why two results are close, especially when I concurrently do the test with jmh? Or how indeed should we deal with this?**

Maybe giving Style1 some fields to store each one's result could make it less redundant. But I still feel not very satisfied. Hope some of you could tell me more.

---

Thank you guys very much. @Andy gave a very good example, I add it here:

```
enum Style4{
    FIRE_BALL,
    ICE_BALL,
    FIRE_ARROW,
    ICE_ARROW;

    private boolean cold;

    private Style4(){
        this.cold = this.toString().contains("ICE");
    }

    public boolean isCold(){
        return cold;
    }
}
```

This fourth style works without mentioning true or false.

Comment: Your benchmark mainly tests the time to generate random numbers. Both methods will be fast enough, and that will never be the cause of any performance problem in a real application. So use the one you find the most readable and maintainable. You could add a third way: a boolean instance variable initialized in the constructor of each enum, and returned by a common isCold() method.

Comment: May I suggest [a third style](http://pastebin.com/sG8Ew3tN)?

Comment: A fourth way, based on the third: don't pass a constructor parameter, just evaluate `toString().contains("ICE")` in the ctor and assign to a field.

Comment: Nit: `this.toString().contains("ICE")?true:false` is equivalent to `this.toString().contains("ICE")`.

Comment: @Andy thanks very much.  I think the fourth is probably the best for it eliminates any explicit true or false evaluation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can improve on the verbosity of style1 somewhat if you use constructors. This will be fast, and (in my opinion) easier to read.

```
enum Style1{
    FIRE_BALL(false),
    ICE_BALL(true),
    FIRE_ARROW(false),
    ICE_ARROW(true);

    private final cold;

    private Style1(boolean cold){
        this.cold = cold;
    }

    public boolean isCold(){
        return cold;
    }
}
```

Note that none of these 3 styles is likely ever to be a hotspot in your code. It is more important to write easier to read code and make adjustments for performance later as needed.

Comment: You can remove the `static` from the `enum` (an enum is always static) and the `final` from `isCold` (you can't subclass it anyway because it's an enum).

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for also catching my typo in the ctor :)

Comment: One thing about this is that boolean parameters aren't necessarily easier to read: if this enum were longer, you might look at it and think "what on earth does 'true' mean?". EJv2 advocates the use of 2-element enums instead of boolean parameters (second page of item 40).

Answer (score 1):

> Can compiler know the destined results and constant-fold Style2 ?

No.

> But why two results are close, especially when I concurrently do the test with jmh? Or how indeed should we deal with this?

As @JB Nizet comments, the majority of the time in your benchmark methods is spent on looking up the `ThreadLocalRandom` instance and generating the next random number.

I'm not sure about this, but I think that the `values()` call must be creating a new array each time you call it.  That could partly explain why you are getting a lot of variability in the timings.  (The JLS is not specific on this, but if `values()` didn't return a new array each time, there is scope for untrusted code to update the array and cause problems for trusted code.)

Comment: Stop the teasing. We want to know the end of the story ;-)

Comment: I had to do some research ... but unfortunately it wasn't conclusive.  See JLS 8.9.3.  It doesn't say whether or not the result is a new array each time, though if it wasn't there is opportunity for mayhem ... if the caller assigns to the array.

Comment: The array is mutable so it has to be a new one, unless the JVM is smart enough to work it it isn't altered but this is not the sort of optimization the JIT does (as it's API specific)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - That was my thinking too.  And if this is the case, the benchmark code is generating garbage which will lead to "noise" in the timings.

Comment: Creating the array add a base load/delay which makes the result appear closer than they would otherwise be.

Comment: Adding new array is probably right. In single thread jmh test, benchmarks were fluctuating about every 7 or 8 rounds.

Answer (score 1):

> But why two results are close, especially when I concurrently do the test with jmh? Or how indeed should we deal with this?

The real code you care about is a method like this

```
return true;
```

However, you add to this

```
if(Style2.values()[random2.nextInt(4)].isCold()){
        cnt++;
    }
```

The method `Style2.value()` is an expensive method which returns a **new** array of all the enum values of the type `Style2`

The method `nextInt(4)` is fairly cheap but includes `%` which is relatively expensive.

You also have an `if` condition which depending on which version of Java you have can be expsive as it contributes to branch misses.  Newer versions of Java use the `CMOV` instruction which handles this much better.

In short, the results are much the same as you spend most of your time doing much the same work, i.e. not in the code you think you are testing.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I barely wanted to make some control factor. Now, it looks like most of these are trifles.